# Slow performance while writing data frame to Azure SQL database using PySpark JDBC

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, azure-sql-database

I am using below `JDBC URL` in `PySpark` to write `data frame` to `Azure SQL Database`. However, I feel that the performance of this write operation is not up to the mark and can be improved by setting up a few extra properties. Are there any workarounds or any parameters that I can add so to improve the JDBC write performance?

```
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://server.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=test;enablePrepareOnFirstPreparedStatementCall=false"
```

Below is the actual data frame write statement.

```
  data_frame.write \
            .mode('overwrite') \
            .format('jdbc') \
            .option('driver', jdbc_driver) \
            .option('user', user) \
            .option('password', password) \
            .option('url', jdbcUrl) \
            .option('dbtable', table + '_STG') \
            .save()
```

Comment: Try setting the job to use the full resources by specifying dynamic allocation property as true.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use Spark to SQL DB connector to write data to SQL database using bulk insert in Scala, please refer to the section [`Write data to Azure SQL database or SQL Server using Bulk Insert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-spark-connector#write-data-to-azure-sql-database-or-sql-server-using-bulk-insert) of Azure offical document `Accelerate real-time big data analytics with Spark connector for Azure SQL Database and SQL Server`, as the screenshot below.

[image]

So I think the problem for you now is how to pass a PySpark dataframe `data_frame` in Python to the code in Scala. You can use the function `registerTempTable` of a dataframe with a table name like `temp_table` as the code and figure below in a databricks python notebook.

```
# register a temp table for a dataframe in Python
data_frame.registerTempTable("temp_table")

%scala
val scalaDF = table("temp_table")
```

[image]

Then to run the bulk insert codes in Scala after `%scala`

```
%scala
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.bulkcopy.BulkCopyMetadata
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config.Config
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect._

/** 
  Add column Metadata.
  If not specified, metadata is automatically added
  from the destination table, which may suffer performance.
*/
var bulkCopyMetadata = new BulkCopyMetadata
bulkCopyMetadata.addColumnMetadata(1, "Title", java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR, 128, 0)
bulkCopyMetadata.addColumnMetadata(2, "FirstName", java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR, 50, 0)
bulkCopyMetadata.addColumnMetadata(3, "LastName", java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR, 50, 0)

val bulkCopyConfig = Config(Map(
  "url"               -> "mysqlserver.database.windows.net",
  "databaseName"      -> "MyDatabase",
  "user"              -> "username",
  "password"          -> "*********",
  "dbTable"           -> "dbo.Clients",
  "bulkCopyBatchSize" -> "2500",
  "bulkCopyTableLock" -> "true",
  "bulkCopyTimeout"   -> "600"
))

scalaDF.bulkCopyToSqlDB(bulkCopyConfig, bulkCopyMetadata)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Performance can be optimized Using Apache Spark connector: SQL Server & Azure SQL -**

First Install the **com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark** Library using **Maven Coordinate** in the Data-bricks cluster and then use below code.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/spark/connector?view=sql-server-ver15][1]

```
df.write \
.format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
.mode("overwrite or append") \
.option("url", url) \
.option("dbtable", table_name) \
.option("user", username) \
.option("password", password) \
.option("mssqlIsolationLevel", "READ_UNCOMMITTED")\
.option("batchsize", as per your need)\
.save()
```